# ANSI questions: "\x1B[?25h" and "\x1BE"

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, ansi-escape

1. What does `"\x1B[?25h"` do?
2. How is `"\x1BE"` different from `"\n"`? According to http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php it "*moves to next line*"? Seems like that's what `"\n"` does?

   I tried `echo "xxx\nxxx\n"` and `echo "xxx\x1BExxx\n"` in PHP and they both output the same thing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These are ANSI escape sequences (also known as VT100 codes) are an early standardisation of control codes pre-dating ASCII.

The escape sequence `\x1BE`, or <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, is NEL or "Next line", and is used on older terminals and mainframes to denote CR+LF, or `\r\n`.

The escape sequence `\x1B[` (<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>) is an example of a Control Sequence Introducer. (`\x9B` is another single-character CSI.) The control sequence `?25h` following it is used to show the cursor.

Most terminals will support these control codes; to enter escape sequences you can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> which should render as `^[` (the C0 code for ESC), followed by the escape code.

References:

- [ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)
- [C0 and C1 control codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes)

Comment: ANSI **escape sequence** covers either escape sequence and control sequence? I learned two are different things [from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence#Control_sequences) [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#Control_character). CSI seems control sequence conceptually.

Comment: @jinbeomhong your link talks about the differences between characters rather than sequences - an escape _character_ might be a `\​` which is not a control character. But I would say all control sequences are special cases of [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence).

Comment: I think it's worth distinguishing NEL as a pure cursor-movement command, as opposed to a CF-LF pair which has semantic meaning in a text file.