# printing \x1bZ in python is weird, explanation needed

Tags: python, hex

The following python code has some weird behavior which I don't understand

```
print('\x1bZ')
```

when I run this code whether in a file or in the interpreter I have a wierd outcome:
[image: terminal result]

actual values as displayed when you write this value to a file as bytes:
[image: bytes in text file]

**Discoveries at time of posting this question**:

1. whether single quotes or double quotes make a difference (they don't)
2. `0x1b` is hex for `27` which in ascii is ESC which matches as displayed with the second picture. This lead me to theorize that the letter `Z` in the string literal can be replaced but as per my test in point number 3 it cant be reproduced with other letters
3. instead of `\x1bZ` (`ESC` and then `Z`) trying `ESC` and then some other letter (I haven't checked all possibilities) yielded no apparent result except from replacing `Z` with `c` which seems to clear the terminal

**Hypothesis that I came up with:**

- This page may be relevant to the answer: https://pypi.org/project/py100/ because I have found a pattern there that resembles weird result: `Esc[?1;Value0c` where `Value` would be replaced by something. also `^[[?1;<n>0c` appears in https://espterm.github.io/docs/VT100%20escape%20codes.html
- Is this some encoding problem?
- Is this related to ANSI character escaping? `[?1;0c` vs `[38;2;` which is used when changing background color of text

**Questions:**

- Why is this particular sequence of characters results in this output?
- What is VT100 and how it is related if it is related? (I visited it's Wikipedia page)
- whether it is possible to print a string that contains this specific sequence without that weird outcome as displayed in the first picture

all help and knowledge about this will be appreciated!!

Comment: `\x1b` is the "ESC" for a system: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011478/ansi-questions-x1b25h-and-x1be You can ensure those characters print using an backslash  escape: `print('\\x1b')` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095796/how-can-i-print-a-single-backslash

Comment: @Glycerine I was already acquainted with the double backslash but its not quite what I'm looking for.
I would like to output the actual value rather than the hex string representation of this value, and moreover: I would like to do so without the weird output.

Thanks for the informing links!

Comment: Why would you want to print an unprintable character (ESC)? Sequences beginning with ESC are instructions to the terminal(emulator); ESC Z means: dear terminal, please send back another ESC-sequnece that contains informations about your features.